# Blender Game Engine Python Flipper Animation

Tags: python, animation, game-engine

Okay. I've been working on this 2D Platform game in the Blender Game Engine lately. I've added some basic motion functions (in Python code), and now I'm getting to animation. I'm using the Blender playAnimation() function, and it works. But, I've found with logic bricks that the animation type that works best in my game is the flipper type. playAnimation() has no flipper mode.

Here's my script so far: (without playAnimation() function in it)

```
import bge
import math

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    xyz = own.localOrientation.to_euler()
    xyz[2] = math.radians(180)

    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events
       [bge.events.RIGHTARROWKEY]:
       own.applyMovement((0, 0.08, 0), True)
       own.worldOrientation = (0, 0, 0)

    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events
       [bge.events.LEFTARROWKEY]:
       own.applyMovement((0, 0.08, 0), True)
       own.localOrientation = xyz.to_matrix()

    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.SPACEKEY]:
        own.applyMovement = ((0, 0, 0.08), True)

main()
```

So, how could I allow flipper animations in this script? Thanks!!

P.S. This code is for a public game project (or several). While I'll really appreciate any code or tips offered, I may or may not be able to give credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

The flipper mode belongs to the action armature. This makes the actuator play the animation forward on activation and backward on deactivation.

The actuator uses the internal animation system to play the action in response the the current status (activated or deactivated) and the animation status (playing, reaching end).

The internal animation system can only act according to the animation status.

The simplest solution is to activate/deactivate the action actuator in flipper mode.

E.g.:

```
import bge
import math

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner

keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

xyz = owner.localOrientation.to_euler()
xyz[2] = math.radians(180)

if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.RIGHTARROWKEY]:
    owner.applyMovement((0, 0.08, 0), True)
    owner.worldOrientation = (0, 0, 0)
    controller.activate("turn right")
    controller.deactivate("turn left")
    controller.deactivate("jump")

if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.LEFTARROWKEY]:
    owner.applyMovement((0, 0.08, 0), True)
    owner.localOrientation = xyz.to_matrix()
    controller.activate("turn left")
    controller.deactivate("turn right")
    controller.deactivate("jump")

if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.SPACEKEY]:
    owner.applyMovement = ((0, 0, 0.08), True)
    controller.activate("jump")
    controller.deactivate("turn right")
    controller.deactivate("turn left")
```

Comment: Do I replace the words in quotations with the name of my animation? I have a single animation named "Run" How, would this look for such an animation?

Comment: activate() and deactivate() expect a connected actuator or the name of a connected actuator. In the sample "jump", "turn left" and "turn right" are the name of actuators.

Comment: In general I would separate physical motion (moving, turning) from animation (walk cycle). While the first one alters the position/orientation within the scene the second one makes it look nice. Both operations should run synchronous to appear as a single task.

Comment: And what would be the logic brick setup for the "Run" actuator in my case? I tried connecting it to the python controller, and then leaving it all to itself, and neither worked.

Comment: When should the "run" animation be played? [playing it is controller.activate("run") - assuming you have an actuator with that name]

Comment: It would run whenever the left key or the right key were pressed. I was just wondering how to connect the run actuator to make it work. I made an actuator named "run" and that didn't seem to make it work with the code (which I edited)

Comment: Make sure the actuator is connected to the python controller (executing the above code). Make sure the actuator names match.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting progress. I added an actuator named "run" and set it as a flipper animation. When using a sensor, it worked. When using the Python activate() command, it played the animation, but not as a flipper animation. It played the full thing instead of only when I had the key pressed down.

Comment: Do not forget you need to explicitly deactivate actuators too.

Comment: Well, currently "run" is the only actuator I have. So when I only activate "run," it still only plays the animation once and not as a flipper. When I put the activate code line and after that the deactive("run"), it does just the same. What's wrong?

Comment: A walk cycle should never be played as flipper. It is a cycle (=loop). After deactivation you should immediately activate a followup action (e.g. standing). To make that smooth you can have the "blend" parameter set.

Comment: I did as you said, but my blend file still isn't working right. I'm so sorry to have to keep bugging you, but if you don't mind, I will supply a blend file showing what I've done so you can maybe point out how to fix it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7lfbr5xhvrhjb3/test.blend?dl=0

Comment: ok, now I understand your concept. You want to make the character run left on left key and run right in right key. I thought you want to turn the object that way.  There are a few points: A) remove main() it makes no sense here. B) Avoid  deactivate and activate of the same actuator at the same time. Deactivation will be the result. C) Avoid activating two action actuators with the conflicting aimation setup - you do not need that -> either it is running or it is idle but not both. This is the reason why it does not play the run action.

Comment: All done. But, the animation still doesn't play as flipper, only as a loop animation - I can't get over that.